# When a user sets his focus in an input box can I set the regional language with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, localization

When a user sets his focus in an input box can I set the regional language with JavaScript?

How would I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to set the language of the browser (for instance, to get the benefit of a built-in spell checker for that input box), or just the language of the text that is displayed on the page?

Answer (score 5):

No.

JavaScript doesn't have that kind of control over the client browser by design. Moreover regional input and related features are OS-level settings and differ in method and invocation by OS.

Comment: @Welbog: Stop black mailing voyager!

Answer (score 0):

Set the language of page or browser?
Language of the page -> Reload the page:

```
<input onfocus="window.location = "http://mypage.com/index_de.html";" />
```